# Batch Solve Tactical Positions

Tags: analysis, software

What is the best software to take a pgn file of positions and solve them in a one-step operation? I am not referring to chess compositions or "mate in n" problems but tactical positions. Is it possible to just highlight positions from a database of positions and have the software compute the best series of follow-up moves and save them to a file? I can perform the function individually on any number of software but I cannot do a batch on any of them.

Answer (score 1):

I use chessbase personally. I can bulk perform tactical analysis.
Alternatively you can download an engine and learn to program with it to perform bulk analysis / positional analysis calculations.

Comment: I appreciate your response but could you please be more explicit as to how to carry out the analysis and then how to save the results to a file for one particular software that you have successfully performed the process. Regardless of which software I use, there is always one ingredient missing and I do not get the desired result.